# Cannot find "Findaws-lambda-runtime.cmake" on ubuntu18.04

Tags: c++, amazon-web-services, cmake, aws-lambda

Trying to build the hello world example, but the cmake always complain

**By not providing "Findaws-lambda-runtime.cmake" in CMAKE_MODULE_PATH this
project has asked CMake to find a package configuration file provided by
"aws-lambda-runtime", but CMake did not find one.**

Environment

- OS : ubuntu18.04.3 LTS,64bits
- install curl by : sudo apt-get install libcurl4-openssl-dev
- install cmake by ubuntu software(cmake version 3.16.1)

Steps to build and install aws lambda cpp

1. git clone https://github.com/awslabs/aws-lambda-cpp.git
2. cd aws-lambda-cpp
3. mkdir build
4. cd build
5. cmake .. -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release -DBUILD_SHARED_LIBS=OFF \
   -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=${PWD}/install
6. make -j2
7. sudo make install

CmakeLists.txt(omit another part, want to make sure find_package works first)

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.5)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 11)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD_REQUIRED ON)

project(aws_cpp_test LANGUAGES CXX)

list(APPEND CMAKE_MODULE_PATH "/home/yyyy/Qt/3rdLibs/aws-lambda-cpp/build/")
list(APPEND CMAKE_MODULE_PATH "/home/yyyy/Qt/3rdLibs/aws-lambda-cpp/cmake/")

find_package(aws-lambda-runtime REQUIRED)

add_executable(${PROJECT_NAME} "main.cpp")
```

I do not use the ec2 to build the project, how could I tell the cmake where should it find the aws-lambda-runtime?

Edit :

Based on the suggestion of Yevhenii Mamontov, I change the CMakeLists.txt to

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.5)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 11)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD_REQUIRED ON)

project(aws_cpp_test LANGUAGES CXX)

set(AWS_LAMBDA_CMAKE "/home/yyyy/Qt/3rdLibs/aws-lambda-cpp/cmake/")
set(CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH "${AWS_LAMBDA_CMAKE};${CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH}")
#check the prefix paths are correct or wrong
foreach(path ${CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH})
  message("Path: " ${path})
endforeach(path)

find_package(aws-lambda-runtime REQUIRED)
```

But it come with different error message

> CMake Error at
>   /home/yyyy/Qt/3rdLibs/aws-lambda-cpp/cmake/aws-lambda-runtime-config.cmake:6
>   (include):   include could not find load file:
>
> ```
> /home/yyyy/Qt/3rdLibs/aws-lambda-cpp/cmake/@CMAKE_PROJECT_NAME@-targets.cmake
> ```

I tried with different paths

```
set(AWS_LAMBDA_CMAKE "/home/yyyy/Qt/3rdLibs/aws-lambda-cpp/build/install")
set(AWS_LAMBDA_CMAKE "/home/yyyy/Qt/3rdLibs/aws-lambda-cpp/build/install/lib/aws-lambda-runtime/cmake")
```

and tried to do not add any new path, but all of them give the same error messages

Edit 2 :

Find a way to make it work

1. Remove the contents of /home/yyyy/Qt/3rdLibs/aws-lambda-cpp/cmake/aws-lambda-runtime-config.cmake
2. set path as set(AWS_LAMBDA_CMAKE "/home/yyyy/Qt/3rdLibs/aws-lambda-cpp/build/install/lib/aws-lambda-runtime/cmake")

However, this solution is awkward, should ask the cmake do not search from the path "/home/yyyy/Qt/3rdLibs/aws-lambda-cpp/cmake" first

Edit 3:

The solution I written in Edit 2 do not work. It fail when I add

```
add_executable(${PROJECT_NAME} "main.cpp")
target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} PUBLIC AWS::aws-lambda-runtime)
```

Error messages are

**Target "aws_cpp_test" links to target "AWS::aws-lambda-runtime" but the
  target was not found.  Perhaps a find_package() call is missing for an
  IMPORTED target, or an ALIAS target is missing?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Find out the solution, all you need to do are set the path of the aws library installed.

Example:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.5)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 11)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD_REQUIRED ON)

project(encoder LANGUAGES CXX)

set(AWS_LAMBDA_CMAKE ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/../../3rdLibs/aws-lambda-cpp/build/install/)
set(AWS_LAMBDA_CPP_SDK ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/../../3rdLibs/aws-sdk-cpp/build/install/)
set(CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH "${AWS_LAMBDA_CMAKE};${CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH};${AWS_LAMBDA_CPP_SDK}")

find_package(CURL REQUIRED)
find_package(aws-lambda-runtime REQUIRED)
find_package(AWSSDK COMPONENTS s3)

add_executable(${PROJECT_NAME} "main.cpp")
target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME}
${CURL_LIBRARIES}
AWS::aws-lambda-runtime
${AWSSDK_LINK_LIBRARIES})

aws_lambda_package_target(${PROJECT_NAME})
```

You may need to install following libs on your ubuntu if you haven't

```
sudo apt-get install zlib1g-dev libssl-dev libcurl4-openssl-dev
```

Answer (score 1):

Could you try to set `CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH` just before the `find_package`?
Something like this:

```
set(AWS_LAMBDA_CMAKE "/home/yyyy/Qt/3rdLibs/aws-lambda-cpp/cmake/")
set(CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH "${AWS_LAMBDA_CMAKE};${CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH}")
```

The first `set()` creates a variable with the path to your lib cmake folder.
The second `set()` appends to `CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH` one more path to search for any package that you've indicated in `find_package()`.

Comment: Thanks, tried with several paths, but all of them fail, looks like cmake always try to find the package from the same path

Comment: Hmm, this is strange, as I can specify path to `../../lib/cmake` and CMake works well. At least Qt5 libs are all finding well. Are you sure this aws-lambda-cpp does have `FindMe.cmake` or etc file? Try to search by your own for that file and if you find, specify to CMakeLists.txt full path to folder where this file is.
Hope that can help you.

Comment: It don't have any any files start with the word "find", weird, indeed

Comment: Than, I may suggest that aws-lambda-cpp with your version does not support that kind of search. Hope that you've seen [this article](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/introducing-the-c-lambda-runtime/)

Comment: Find out why, it do not need any Find*, all you need is set the paths to the install folder

Answer (score 0):

I got the same error, the answer marked as solution worked pretty well, but I also found tha this works:

```
set(aws-lambda-runtime_DIR /lib/aws-lambda/lib64/aws-lambda-runtime/cmake/)
```

I am using CMake 3.13 and had the lambda runtime installed on "/lib/aws-lambda" when running tha cmake as instructed by the installation instructions:

```
cmake .. -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/lib/aws-lambda
```